# Google Cloud Platform deleting a project

Tags: permissions, project, google-cloud-platform

I have the following scenario and sequence of events:

1. Google Account A creates a new project foo in the Google Developers Console.
2. Account A then turns on billing for project foo by entering their credit card
3. Account A then gives project ownership permissions for foo to Account B
4. Account B logs in and changes the project permissions of Account A to Can view for project foo
5. Account A now cannot disable billing or delete project foo
6. Account B is deleted
7. Project foo is in a state where the billing cannot be disabled, and the project cannot be deleted.

How can Account A delete project foo or disable billing?

Any help would be very much appreciated

Update: 01/20/15
After contacting the Google billing department, I got the following reply implying there is no solution to this issue.

---

> I understand that you'd like to change the project owner or delete this project. For security and privacy reasons, I unfortunately cannot perform any such changes, as these can only be performed by a project owner. If your main concern is related to billing and if it's your credit card used on this account, in order to stop future charges simply advise your financial institution about the unauthorized charges.
>
> Should the current project owner not wish to make any of the changes you requested in this case or is unable to, regrettably the only options available were previously mentioned. It's recommended to always have more than a single project owner in order to avoid any complications that may arise for best practice.
>
> I appreciate your understanding on this matter.

Comment: I had a further look into this and I believe the reply provided by Billing Support was accurate as account B is not deleted, but active and is the current project owner. Please note that Google is not in a position to mediate or adjudicate disputes between third parties. We recommend that you raise your concerns with the account B owner directly. If you believe that the account B owner is unlawfully restricting access to your project, we recommend that you contact law enforcement. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will mark this as the correct answer for the moment. I consider this a Google bug however. If Account A is the billing owner, no one other than Account A should be allowed to change its project permissions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to contact the billing team at:

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

They will help you to solve this issue.

Regards,
Paolo.

Comment: I thought I would share my experience with the Google billing team. It may help other people going down this path. 4-5days after contacting them I got a reply that didn't help. I updated my original response with their reply.